# QGIS Oracle-Spatial-GeoRaster-Plugin not working

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, oracle-spatial

I am having trouble with Oracle-Spatial-GeoRaster-Plugin in QGIS (running on Windows 7 Professional N 64bit). The connection to my database on an external Oracle-Server obviously works as it shows the containing rasters in the database. But as soon as I try to open a raster an error message comes up with the information that the connection could not be established. I should check the connection options and make sure the GDAL-Georaster-Plugin is installed.

I tried it with three independent standalone versions of QGIS (all 64bit):

- QGIS 2.14.3 running with GDAL 2.1.0
- QGIS 2.12.2 running with GDAL 1.11.3
- QGIS 2.10.1 running with GDAL 1.11.2

On my system I installed GDAL 2.1.0 with gdal-oracle-oci-driver (with OSGeo4W) and I know I could load Oracle rasters in QGIS with an earlier version of QGIS. When I updated the GDAL-version on my system it was not working any more.

My Questions:

- Is there another plugin apart from the "oracle-spatial-georaster"-plugin like written in the error message ("GDAL-georaster)? I don't find it.
- With which GDAL-Version is QGIS running? I thought QGIS installs its own GDAL-version and doesn't use the system-GDAL, but apparently its not working any more since I installed the recent GDAL-version on my system.
- Is there any other solution or has anybody hints of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: no, there is no other plugin needed. The "Oracle Spatial GeoRaster" plugin is all you need. But then again, there are so many things that can go wrong ... A lot can depend on where you got the GDAL build from and how the Georaster plugin was built. As a separate dynamic library ? In the GDAL core ?

Then also you are using Windows which adds its own lot of complexities with all te mix up of 32 vs 64-bit kernel and libraries ...

You should be able to access the GDAL version you are using with QGIS from the command line, right ? Let's confirm that works fine all the way.

What happens when you do the following ? Can you see the GeoRaster plugin ?

```
$ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 2.0.1, released 2015/09/15
```

and

```
$ gdalinfo --formats | grep GeoRaster
GeoRaster -raster- (rw+s): Oracle Spatial GeoRaster
```

Also you may want to check that your rasters can be accessed, just to make sure the connectivity is all right all the way down to the tables in your database. For example (substitute with your own connection details):

```
$ gdalinfo georaster:scott/tiger@localhost:1521/orcl121,us_rasters,georaster
Driver: GeoRaster/Oracle Spatial GeoRaster
Files: none associated
Size is 512, 512
Coordinate System is `'
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=geor:scott/tiger@localhost:1521/orcl121,US_RASTERS_RDT_01,1
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[4299x4299x3] CellDepth=8BIT_U SRID=26943
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=geor:scott/tiger@localhost:1521/orcl121,US_RASTERS_RDT_01,2
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[4299x4299x3] CellDepth=8BIT_U SRID=26943
  SUBDATASET_3_NAME=geor:scott/tiger@localhost:1521/orcl121,US_RASTERS_RDT_01,3
  SUBDATASET_3_DESC=[4299x4299x3] CellDepth=8BIT_U SRID=26943
  SUBDATASET_4_NAME=geor:scott/tiger@localhost:1521/orcl121,US_RASTERS_RDT_01,4
  SUBDATASET_4_DESC=[4299x4299x3] CellDepth=8BIT_U SRID=26943
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

All this to confirm that your GDAL environment is setup correctly. The next step is to verify that QGIS uses that environment correctly too.

BTW, what is the exact error you see ? Is that some GDAL exception ? Or does it come from QGIS.

One possible debug technique is to enable GDAL debugging:

```
export CPL_DEBUG=ON
```

Do that in the terminal window you start QGIS from. You should then see all sorts of debugging messages coming out on stdout (= in your terminal window). Maybe that will tell you more ...

On windows do

```
set CPL_DEBUG=ON
```

Then when you run QGIS (in that window) you should see things like this (you also see this if you run the gdalinfo command line):

```
GDAL: Auto register /opt/gdal/gdal-2.0.1/lib/gdalplugins/gdal_JP2OpenJPEG.so using GDALRegister_JP2OpenJPEG.
GDAL: Auto register /opt/gdal/gdal-2.0.1/lib/gdalplugins/gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.so using GDALRegister_ECW_JP2ECW.
GDAL: Auto register /opt/gdal/gdal-2.0.1/lib/gdalplugins/gdal_GEOR.so using GDALRegister_GEOR.
GDAL: Auto register /opt/gdal/gdal-2.0.1/lib/gdalplugins/ogr_OCI.so using RegisterOGROCI.
```

Comment: Everything you describe works well. The GDAL-Version, the GeoRaster-plugin in the formats and also the connection. I guess the debugging thing is a GDAL-option for the GDAL-commands or can I also see QGIS-logs somewhere (in the protocol window I don't see errors in my case).

Comment: The exact error (in my German QGIS) is: "Öffnen gescheitert: Die Verbindung zu geor:user/pw@IP:port/db,table_rdt,id schlug fehl. Bitte überprüfen Sie die Verbindungsparameter und stellen Sie sicher, dass die GDAL-Georaster-Erweiterung installiert ist."

Comment: I just realized you are using Windows, right ? Then you need to do "set CPL_DEBUG=ON" in the command line window where you launch QGIS from. It tells the GDAL libraries to print out debugging information. That should show the drivers it loads. The output should come to the command line window you launched QGIS from ...

Comment: The error message talks about two possibilities: one is that it is unable to find or activate the Georaster plugin. The other is that somehow the database connection fails. But you say that you are able to access other data in the same database using QGIS ... same user and password ? Is that vector data ? So it looks more like a problem with the plugin. Are you sure the path settings and other GDAL settings are correct ? I assume they are otherwise you would not be able to run he GDAL commands ...

Comment: The error logs don't appear in the command line...
However, the database connection works as I am able to visualize vector data in an Oracle Spatial layer with the same connection. Also in the GeoRaster-Plugin the connection seems to work as it shows the table that contain my rasterdata. But when I try to add a specific raster image to the map, the error message appears...

Comment: So then the error looks definitely to be on the QGIS side ... Maybe some sort of incompatibility ? Sorry, I can't be of more help ...